# How can I convert a dict_keys list to integers

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to find a way of converting a list within dict_keys() to an integer so I can use it as a trigger to send to another system. My code (below) imports a list of 100 words (a txt file with words each on a new line) which belong to 10 categories (e.g. the first 10 words belong to category 1, second 10 words belong to category 2 etc...).

**Code:**

```
from numpy.random import choice
from collections import defaultdict

number_of_elements = 10

Words = open('file_location').read().split()

categories = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(words)):
    categories[i/number_of_elements].append(words[i])

category_labels = categories.keys()

category_labels
```

**Output**

```
dict_keys([0.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.9, 5.0, 0.5, 1.9, 8.0, 9.0, 1.3, 2.7, 3.9, 9.2, 9.4, 7.2, 4.2, 8.6, 5.1, 5.4, 3.3, 1.0, 6.6, 7.4, 7.7, 8.4, 5.8, 9.8, 0.7, 8.8, 2.1, 7.0, 6.4, 4.3, 0.1, 2.5, 3.8, 1.2, 6.9, 7.1, 5.6, 0.4, 5.3, 2.9, 7.3, 3.5, 9.5, 8.2, 2.8, 3.1, 0.9, 2.3, 8.1, 4.0, 6.3, 6.7, 4.5, 0.2, 1.7, 2.2, 8.9, 1.4, 7.6, 9.1, 7.8, 5.5, 4.8, 0.6, 3.2, 2.4, 6.5, 9.9, 9.6, 1.5, 6.0, 3.7, 4.7, 3.4, 5.9, 4.1, 1.6, 6.8, 9.3, 3.6, 8.5, 8.7, 0.3, 0.8, 7.5, 5.2, 2.6, 4.6, 5.7, 7.9, 6.1, 1.8, 8.3, 6.2, 9.7, 4.4])
```

**What I need:**

I would like the first number before the point (e.g. if it was 6.7, I just want the 6 as an int).

Thank you in advance for any help and/or advice!

Answer (score 3):

Just convert your keys to integers using a list comprehension; note that there is no need to call `.keys()` here as iteration over the dictionary directly suffices:

```
[int(k) for k in categories]
```

You may want to bucket your values directly into integer categories rather than by floating point values:

```
categories = defaultdict(list)
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    categories[int(i / number_of_elements)].append(word)
```

I used `enumerate()` to pair words up with their index, rather than use `range()` plus indexing back into `words`.

Comment: `0.5 == 0` and `0.0 == 0` lose data when a key is duplicated ! Question got bad idea and the answer to  ....

Comment: @dsgdfg: which is why the OP *may* want to bucket by integer values. However, where in the code is data lost?

Comment: Okay you `True` but losing index after do that. How to use/compare values after ?

Comment: @dsgdfg: the first approach, using a list comprehension, keeps the original bucketing. I suggested the second approach because perhaps the OP wanted the bucketing to be done per integer value instead. We don't know what problem is being solved here anyway. Pick one that fits your usecase.